# MUI - SELECT, how can I add a fixed layer inside the popper Paper

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working to customize Material-UI Select field, and I am trying to add a fixed layer inside the select popper Paper, like the picture shows:

[image]

I tried to add a html div tag inside the Select children:

```
   <Select
       value={selectedValue}
       onChange={onChange}
       inputProps={{
         id,
         name: id,
       }}
       classes={{
         icon: classes.icon,
       }}
       MenuProps={{
         anchorOrigin: {
           vertical:   "bottom",
           horizontal: "left",
         },
         transformOrigin: {
           vertical:   "top",
           horizontal: "left",
         },
         getContentAnchorEl: null,
       }}
     >
       <MenuItem
         key={item[0]}
         value={item[0]}
       >
         {item[0]}
       </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem
         key={item[1]}
         value={item[1]}
       >
         {item[1]}
       </MenuItem>

       **<div>fixed layer here</div>**

     </Select>
```

but the code doesn't work, it seems the SelectField only accept **MenuItem** or **Option** as children and will wrap all inside **ul**, can anyone help me to find a solution to add this fixed layer inside the Select Popper Paper ? Thank you

Comment: if you want it clickable you can wrap the <div> in a menuitem

Comment: hi, Casey thank you , as you can see in the picture, the position of the layer is fixed and the menuItems are scrolllAble, if I wrap <div> in a menuItem, I will have to scroll to the end to see the layer.

Comment: I see what you mean, this question might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041659/material-ui-fixed-menuitem